# Loosing data in rotation android

Tags: android, screen-rotation, onsaveinstancestate

I'm a beginner and french, so sorry for my english.
I have a problem, I loose data in rotation of screen.
I will do a quizz, the score is correctly saved but not the current question, so when I turn the phone a new question is created :/
Maybe my question is in color, with different animations and 4 responses... and it's impossible to stay in bundle?
My game activity :

```
    public static final String BUNDLE_STATE_SCORE = "currentScore";
    public static final String BUNDLE_STATE_QUESTION = "currentQuestion";

 @Override    
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        System.out.println("GameActivity::onCreate()");
        mQuestionBank= this.generateQuestions();
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(BUNDLE_STATE_SCORE);
            mNumberOfQuestions = savedInstanceState.getInt(BUNDLE_STATE_QUESTION);
        } else {
            mScore = 0;
            mNumberOfQuestions = 4;
        }

   @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt(BUNDLE_STATE_SCORE, mScore);
        outState.putInt(BUNDLE_STATE_QUESTION, mNumberOfQuestions);

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

Comment: are you saving your current question?  I don't see it.  All i see is # of questions and score being saved.

Comment: I have use that in manifest android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>

Comment: thats work's :)